# "add_row_annotation" in "main_heatmap" in "iheatmapr" sets wrong annotation in the output heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

i'm using the package "iheatmapr" (cant use another though), and tried to add row annotation to the genes i'm working on. I created a data frame with the name of the gene, and 2 more column describing the complex the gene participates in, and the pathway it participates as well (data frame attached).
When using the "add_row_annotation" to the "main_heatmap" it changes the complex and the pathway that the gene belongs to. I checked for the roght order and it's the same.
Has anyone ever encountred that? Thanks!

- part of the data frame for the annotation:
  data.frame("Genes" = c("MT-ND1", "MT-ND2", "MT-ND3", "MT-ND4", "MT-ND4L"', "MT-ND5")
  "Attribute" = c("complex1", "complex1", "complex1", "complex1", "complex1", "complex1")
  "Pathway" = c("respiratory", "respiratory", "respiratory", "respiratory", "respiratory", "respiratory"))

I tried to create a heatmap of aroung 100 genes, and "tagging" each gene after clustering them, in order to analyse furthet. When doing so, the add_row_annotation scrambled the labels and the result is incorrect...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.